# iOS 13 Changed circular buttons to diagonal

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have the following two buttons in a view controller and they are displaying circular buttons as I need in iOS 12 and XCode 11, but when I use iOS 13 and XCode 11, they are diagonal as shown in the pictures.

```
self.saveBtn.frame.size = CGSize(width:70,height:70)
self.saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.saveBtn.frame.size.height/2.0
self.saveBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
self.saveBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
self.saveBtn.clipsToBounds = true
self.saveBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size:18)
self.saveBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

self.cancelBtn.frame.size = CGSize(width:70,height:70)
self.cancelBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.cancelBtn.frame.size.height/2.0
self.cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
self.cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
self.cancelBtn.clipsToBounds = true
self.cancelBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size:18)
self.cancelBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

[image: Xcode 11 and iOS12]

[image: XCode 11 and iOS 13]

How do I convert those buttons back to circular?

Comment: do you use constraints for your button after adding it on parent view?

Comment: @sheshnath Yes, I did add constraints after adding to the parent view, but why is it still working in iOS 12 and not on iOS 13

Comment: I am not sure, may some UI rendering mechanism change in iOS 13, try to add this on viewDidLayoutSubviews, see if this one works

Comment: @sheshnath, try to add what?

Comment: this issue occurs because your button or subview height will changed fix this and get proper height. you can try this also: self.saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.saveBtn.frame.size.width/2.0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but try this one

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.saveBtn.frame.size = CGSize(width:70,height:70)
        self.saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.saveBtn.frame.size.height/2.0
        self.saveBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.saveBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.saveBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        self.saveBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size:18)
        self.saveBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        self.cancelBtn.frame.size = CGSize(width:70,height:70)
        self.cancelBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.cancelBtn.frame.size.height/2.0
        self.cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        self.cancelBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        self.cancelBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size:18)
        self.cancelBtn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
   }
}
```

Comment: so the button is not made programmatically right? , try once not setting the button frame programmatically I mean comment out the code - self.saveBtn.frame.size = CGSize(width:70,height:70)

Comment: Ok, I'll try myself and get back to you

Comment: appreciate it, please let me know.